# How can I create a timer in a survey in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I need to make a survey form where each page of the survey is timed. Once the timer runs out, the form should automatically advance to the next page.

Is this possible using Google Forms?

Comment: Application recommendations are off-topic for this site (see the [help/on-topic]). If you rewrite your question to concern a single webapp (like Google Forms), it may be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ted J 18/12/2013](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zWqx7yCs4Yg) the answer is:

> Currently, we can't time a quiz per se using Google Apps Script.  However, you can do a few things like limit how many responses a Form can take or put a hard stop time on the Form.

However, there is a free Add-on:

[image: https://clients5.google.com/webstore/detail/formlimiter/clflahnkjeannplpafofekagclpmijkl?container=GOOGLE_FORM&utm_source=docs.google.com&utm_medium=apps-widget&ref=https://docs.google.com&hl=en&gl=GB&authuser=0&xpc=%7B%22cn%22:%22rLEgmW8EvB%22,%22tp%22:1,%22osh%22:true,%22ppu%22:%22https://docs.google.com/robots.txt%22,%22lpu%22:%22https://clients5.google.com/robots.txt%22%7D]

I would envisage some inherent problems with any timer due to differences in download speeds and internet unavailability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are you aware of alternatives to Google Forms that may enable me to accomplish this?

Comment: @arungm29 You can use http://quizandsurveymaster.com/ to achieve the same on WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

There is another nifty little addon for Google Forms - https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/extended_forms/763170157069 .

This addon allows you to add a Timer to your Google Forms, like this

[image]